# What is the proper Rockspec filename for a new luarock?

Tags: lua, luarocks

According to this page: http://luarocks.org/en/Creating_a_rock

> This should be saved in a file called luafruits-1.0-1.rockspec. The
>   name must contain lowercase versions of the "package" and "version"
>   fields, or else LuaRocks will complain.

However, other luarocks are using `rockspec` as the filename.  Where can I get more information on `rockspec` vs `name-VER-REV.rockspec`?  Luarocks itself uses a `rockspec` filename: https://github.com/keplerproject/luarocks/blob/master/rockspec

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `rockspec` filename is version-agnostic, but can be used only with the `luarocks make` command (hence, it's useful for development/bootstrapping). For redistributing a rockspec (for example, sending for inclusion in http://luarocks.org), use the versioned name. Some devs also keep a `rockspecs/` dir in their repo containing the rockspecs for their releases: users can then use those files directly if they wish so, by using commands such as 
`luarocks install https://raw.github.com/lua4web/refser/v0.2/rockspecs/refser-0.2-1.rockspec` (using the raw.github.com pathname).